# Git not using staged sources in pre-commit hook

Tags: java, git, maven, githooks

I use this script in pre-commit hook to make some checks before I push the changes to git.

```
#!/bin/bash
mvn clean compile -DskipTests &> $TEMP/cc.txt &
A=$!
wait $A
A=$?

if test "$A" != "0"
then
  cat $TEMP/cc.txt
  exit 1
fi

mvn javadoc:javadoc -T 8 &> $TEMP/jd.txt &
B=$!

mvn pmd:cpd-check &> $TEMP/pmd.txt &
C=$!

mvn org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent test org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:report -T 8 &> $TEMP/jcc.txt &
D=$!

mvn checkstyle:checkstyle -Dcheckstyle.config.location=https://XXXX &> $TEMP/cs.txt &
E=$!

wait $B
B=$?

wait $C
C=$?

wait $D
D=$?

wait $E
E=$?

mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarcubeXXXX &> $TEMP/cq.txt &
F=$!
wait $F
F=$?

echo "compile $A, javadoc $B, pmd $C, jacoco $D, checkstyle $E, sonar $F"
if test "$A$B$C$D$E$F" != "000000"
then
  if test "$D" != "0"
  then
    cat $TEMP/jcc.txt
  fi

  if test "$F" != "0"
  then
    cat $TEMP/cq.txt
  fi
  exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

But as long as the pre-commit-hook is running (5 minutes), I can not work and change sourcefiles.

I use Sourcetree to commit, sourcetree makes a difference between staged and unstaged files. While commiting files sourcetree executes this command:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false commit -q -F C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\fbox5amv.k5f
```

### Question:

How to access the intended codebase (what is currently pushed + what I have staged and try to commit) only but not the changes that are not staged in Sourcetree?

I have used subversion-commit-hooks before, they are server-side and they was able to extract the prospective codebase only.

Any idea?

Comment: Go forward to Subversion is something I am not allowed to do.

Comment: why not just committing, then amending until you are happy, then push (or resetting?)

Comment: Are you sure that you want git to run your tests? Consider using a CI server. Your approach will make your users **hate** you for making a quick thing really, really slow.

Comment: I use gitlab for CI having the same checks. How can "slow" be a argument? A commit is a commitment. Yes I hate to have the checks twice (in commit on local and push on server) but I can not go forward to Subversion. Amend is not an option because every amend is an commit who triggers the pre-commit hook and makes no difference between staged and unstaged changes. If I do the checks on gitlab-server 90% of commitments will fail (and trust me, gitlab is much more slow than my local machine, so i have to wait longer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there was no other answer there might be no way to access staged+committed+pushed changes without the unstaged changes before a commit(ment) has been made.

Therefore I had to change from a pre-commit hook to a `post-commit` hook and change the script to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf ../committed
mkdir ../committed
cp -rf * ../committed/
cd ../committed
git stash save -u

mvn clean compile -DskipTests &> $TEMP/cc.txt &
(...)
```